# How do I get the index of a 2d arraylist to be used in the ArrayList.set() method?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a 2D ArrayList and I want to replace one of the elements with something else by using the `set` method.

According to the Java API:

```
set(int index, E Element)
```

is the constructor. How do I input the index, given that the ArrayList is 2D?

Comment: When you say "2D ArrayList", do you mean that you have an `ArrayList` of `ArrayLists`, i.e. `ArrayList<ArrayList<E>>`?

Answer (score 3):

If you have a two-dimensional `ArrayList`, then what you need to do is

```
outerList.get(x).set(y, newValueAtXY);
```

...which gets the row at index `x` and sets element `y` in that row to `newValueAtXY`.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this while searching:

```
array.get(i1).put(i2, value);
```

I think, it can be modified like this:

```
array.get(i1).set(i2, value);
```

I hope it works.

Comment: @Louis, you are faster than me.:)